# Problems in setting the To field in the mail composer of iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using this code to send an email on the click of a button:

```
   -(IBAction)btn_emailClick:(id)sender{
       // checking for the blank Email id field.
       if ([[patientDemogDic valueForKey:@"email"]  isEqualToString:@""]){

       }
       else{

           if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){

               MFMailComposeViewController * mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
               mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
               [mailer setSubject:@""];
               NSArray * toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[btn_emailClick currentTitle],
               nil];
               [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];
               NSString *emailBody = @"";
               [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
               mailer.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
               [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:Nil];
           }
           else{

               UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure" message:@"Your
               device doesn't support the composer sheet" delegate:self 
               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"otherButtonTitles:nil];
               [alert show];
           }
       }
   }
```

everything is working very fine but as soon as the email address is this:-
    nupur_Pal.iwalMeditab,.<>{}[]!#$%^&*_@meditab.com 
 The "To" field in the email composer screen is not showing this email address. I had debugged it several times but not able to find the proper reason for that.

Comment: Did you get the email id right in your question?

Comment: have you checked in NSLog what [btn_emailClick currentTitle] is returning?

Comment: yeah! every other email id is working fine except from this, so there is no question of NSLog or anything. FYI I have checked that also.

Comment: Maybe this is because `nupur_Pal.iwalMeditab,.<>{}[]!#$%^&*_@meditab.com` is [not a valid email address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Invalid_email_addresses)?

Answer (score 1):

Make `IBOutlet` For email `UIButton`

and try following code

```
   NSArray * toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:emailButton.titleLabel.text,
    nil];
    [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];
```

Comment: Already an IBoutlet is created for that button, so there is no issue for connection as other Email id's are working fine.

Comment: I have found a solution for this  and stated in the bove comment.